# Stemcompletion in R

Tags: r, tm

I am working on text mining in R, here are few documents from my corpus, after removing punctuation, numbers, URL's and stopwords.

```
 myStopwords <- setdiff(myStopwords, c("r", "big"))
 myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)
 myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stripWhitespace)
 myCorpusCopy <- myCorpus
 for (i in c(1:2, 320))
 {
   cat(paste0("[", i, "] "))
   writeLines(strwrap(as.character(myCorpus[[i]]), 60))
 }

[1] examples calling java code r
[2] simulating mapreduce r big data analysis using flights data
rbloggers
[320] r reference card data mining now cran lists many useful r
functions packages data mining applications
```

After that, I am trying for stemming as below,

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemCompletion, dictionary=myCorpusCopy)
```

When I try running a `for` loop, it is showing `NA`, as below

```
 for (i in c(1:2, 320))
 {
 cat(paste0("[", i, "] "))
 writeLines(strwrap(as.character(myCorpus[[i]]), 60))
 }

[1] NA
[2] NA
[320] NA
```

Any idea where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem with a built-in data set:

```
data("crude")

myCorpus     <- as.VCorpus(crude)
myCorpusCopy <- myCorpus  
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemCompletion, dictionary=myCorpusCopy)
```

I found that after the last line the `myCorpus` object's elements have more fields in their structure, such as `meta` and `content` in my case and now the elemnts are named character vectors.

You can still access the elements:

`myCorpus[[1]]`

```
Diamond Shamrock Corp said that\neffect today it had cut it contract price for crude oil by\n1.50 dlrs a barrel.\n    The reduct bring it post price for West Texas\nIntermedi to 16.00 dlrs a barrel, the copani said.\n    "The price reduct today was made in the light of falling\noil product price and a weak crude oil market," a company\nspokeswoman said.\n    Diamond is the latest in a line of U.S. oil compani that\nhav cut it contract, or posted, price over the last two days\ncit weak oil markets.\n Reuter 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "content" 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <NA> 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "meta"
```

but the `as.character()` method is hitting the opposite part of the new structure (`str()`) of the object's elements from what you want. Now the body text is apparently actually stored as `names`.

I was able to fix the loop like this:

```
for (i in c(1:2, length(myCorpus)))
{
  cat(paste0("[", i, "] "))
  writeLines(strwrap(as.character(names(myCorpus[[i]])), 60))
}
```

> ```
> [1] Diamond Shamrock Corp said that effect today it had cut it
> contract price for crude oil by 1.50 dlrs a barrel.  The
> reduct bring it post price for West Texas Intermedi to
> 16.00 dlrs a barrel, the copani said.  "The price reduct
> today was made in the light of falling oil product price
> and a weak crude oil market," a company spokeswoman said.
> Diamond is the latest in a line of U.S. oil compani that
> hav cut it contract, or posted, price over the last two
> days cit weak oil markets.  Reuter
>
> [2] OPEC may be forc to meet befor a schedul June session to
> readdress it product cutting agr if the organ want to halt
> the current slide in oil prices, oil industri analyst said.
> "The movement to higher oil price was never to be as easy a
> OPEC thought. They may need an emerg meet to sort out th
> problems," said Daniel Yergin, director of Cambridg Energy
> Research Associates, CERA.  Analyst and oil industri sourc
> said the problem OPEC face is excess oil suppli in world
> oil markets.  "OPEC problem is not a price problem but a
> production issu and must be address in that way," said Paul
> Mlotok, oil analyst with Salomon Brother Inc.  He said the
> market earlier optim about OPEC and its abl to keep product
> under control have given way to a pessimist outlook that
> the organ must address soon if it wish to regain the initi
> in oil prices.  But some other analyst were uncertain that
> even an emerg meet would address the problem of OPEC
> production abov the 15.8 mln bpd quota set last December.
> "OPEC has to learn that in a buyer market you cannot have
> deem quotas, fix price and set differentials," said the
> region manag for one of the major oil compani who spoke on
> condit that he not be named. "The market is now tri to
> teach them that lesson again," he added.  David T. Mizrahi,
> editor of Mideast reports, expect OPEC to meet befor June,
> although not immediately. However, he is not optimist that
> OPEC can address it princip problems.  "They will not meet
> now as they tri to take advantag of the wint demand to sell
> their oil, but in late March and April when demand
> slackens," Mizrahi said.  But Mizrahi said that OPEC is
> unlik to do anyth more than reiter it agreement to keep
> output at 15.8 mln bpd."  Analyst said that the next two
> month will be critic for OPEC abil to hold togeth price and
> output.  "OPEC must hold to it pact for the next six to
> eight weeks sinc buyer will come back into the market
> then," said Dillard Sprigg of Petroleum Analysi Ltd in New
> York.  But Bijan Moussavar-Rahmani of Harvard Univers
> Energy and Environ Polici Center said that the demand for
> OPEC oil ha been rise through the first quarter and this
> may have prompt excess in it production.  "Demand for their
> (OPEC) oil is clear abov 15.8 mln bpd and is probabl closer
> to 17 mln bpd or higher now so what we ar see character as
> cheat is OPEC meet this demand through current production,"
> he told Reuter in a telephon interview.  Reuter
> [20] Argentin crude oil product was down 10.8 pct in Januari
> 1987 to 12.32 mln barrels, from 13.81 mln barrel in Januari
> 1986, Yacimiento Petrolifero Fiscales said.  Januari 1987
> natur gas output total 1.15 billion cubic metrers, 3.6 pct
> higher than 1.11 billion cubic metr produced in Januari
> 1986, Yacimiento Petrolifero Fiscal added.  Reuter
> ```